# How to step through a GIF animation based on the browser's scroll position?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, gif

I have a GIF that I will use in a React web app I am building. I want to be able to step through the animation based on the scroll position of the site. 
I.e. when I have scrolled through 50% of the page, then I want the gif to display the image at its 50% position.
The gif will be in a div, position:fixed. So it will always live in the top corner of the browser.

The web app is a react app so if it's possible that there's a react library that implements this then that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you share some code you wrote so far? Have you tried sth?

Comment: I'm honestly lost on where to start. So i was wondering if i could maybe find some ideas here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be at least one ready made React implementation for dealing with the interaction with/playing of the GIF that may be able to assist you in your project.

[React Gif Player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gif-player) is a React component which creates a GIF player similar to Facebook's implementation. It also comes with a `pause` function (and an example), which you may be able to use to programatically pause the GIF at corresponding points based on your scroll position.

[Gif Frames](https://github.com/benwiley4000/gif-frames) is a pure JavaScript tool for extracting GIF frames and saving to file. You may be able to create individual frames and correspond frames with certain points of the scroll.

I'm not aware of a gif player that implements exactly what you were hoping for, although others may be able to assist in this regard. If not, you may have to use a combination of, or do a full implementation yourself.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks! These look promising. I'll try them out and let you know what I get to.